# How to hold a screen

Tags: turbo-c++

I have a basic code on C++ that can display a string using the puts function and then has a break after it to return to a menu screen, but I have no way to sustain the string itself on screen. It just skips ahead because of the break. 
I need a  certain function that can hold the screen and change only when a key is pressed

Comment: Obligatory reminder that Turbo C++ is old, and you should get a compiler from this century.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it's a class project, got no choice

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read this: [ask]. As it stands here the question is very unclear. What is _"I need a certain function that can hold the screen and change only when a key is pressed"_ supposed to mean?

Comment: @jabberwocky all I'm asking is for a function that can hold a screen till I press literally any key

Comment: _"hold a screen"_ : what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat saying that  that Turbo C++ is old is really an understatement.

Comment: In turbo C++, from what i remember it is done by ```getch()``` function

Comment: no code no useful description .... its unclear what you mean by break and by hold ... its unclear if you got a loop (ended by an menu option or special key hit) or none of that and you issue is that your app end before you can see the output ... voting for close for now

Answer (score 0):

You can use **getch()** which actually waits for character input from the keyboard but it seems like holding a screen. Similarly, any function or similar concept can be used to do the same e.g. scanf(), etc.

You can switch to another environment(IDE) which does not require this concept of the screen holding like Dev C++, Code::Blocks, etc. at beginner level and Visual Studios, Eclipse, etc. at a higher level.